# Loop a list with a list of lists in pairs

Tags: python, list, for-loop

EDITED: In me trying to exemplify the coding issue I made a mistake in regards to my desired outcome. I have updated the outcome to my ACTUAL desired outcome.

I have a list of lists called `list_of_lists_1` that I whish to loop over in parallel with a
**sister list** *(if that is a term in coding)* called `list_of_lists_2`, and a third list called `person_list`. `list_of_lists_1` and `list_of_lists_2` have the same number of elements both in total and within each list of lists. Each element in `person_list` should loop with its respective list in `list_of_lists_1` and `list_of_lists_2` i.e. `person_a` will loop in tandem with lists `[1, 3, 5]` and `[2, 4, 6]`. Just as `persin_b` will loop with `["7", "9", "11"]` and `["8", "10", "12"]` etc.

```
# create lists
list_of_lists_1 = [["1", "3", "5"], ["7", "9", "11"], ["13", "15", "17"]]
list_of_lists_2 = [["2", "4", "6"], ["8", "10", "12"], ["14", "16", "18"]]
person_list = ["person_a", "person_b", "person_c"]
```

I have tried the following code. However, the output only amounts to about 50 pct. of the desired outcome.

```
# loop
for i in range(0, len(list_of_lists_1)):

    outcome = person_list[i] + list_of_lists_1[i][i] + list_of_lists_2[i][i]
    
    # some functions and other interesting stuff!

    print(outcome)

person_a12
person_b910
person_c1718
```

```
# desired outcome (Has been edited)
person_a12
person_a34
person_a56
person_b78
person_b910
person_b1112
person_c1314
person_c1516
person_c1718
```

How would I achieve the desired outcome?

Thank you.

Comment: Use `zip()` to loop over lists in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `zip()` to loop over lists in parallel.

Then you can use a nested loop  to combine the elements of the nested lists in `list_of_lists_X`.

Given:

```
list_of_lists_1 = [["1", "3", "5"], ["7", "9", "11"], ["13", "15", "17"]]
list_of_lists_2 = [["2", "4", "6"], ["8", "10", "12"], ["14", "16", "18"]]
person_list = ["person_a", "person_b", "person_c"]
```

Your result can be constructed via:

```
for suffixes_1, suffixes_2, name in zip(list_of_lists_1, list_of_lists_2, person_list):
    for s1, s2 in zip(suffixes_1, suffixes_2):
        outcome = name + s1 + s2
        print(outcome)
```

Comment: Only correcting for the assumed typo of an extra "s" in `list(s)_of_lists_2` I still get the error `NameError: name 'suffix1' is not defined`. What am I misunderstanding? Btw. Thank you.

Comment: I left out part of the generator expression.

Comment: It works @Barmar. However, I made a mistake regarding my desired outcome when trying to simplify my question... I have updated the desired outcome.

Comment: Great! Thank you @Barmar. I only removed ")" at the end of the second line.

Comment: @JonSG The underscore is already in `person_list`, I don't need to add it. The extra `)` came from copying the generator version improperly.

Answer (score 1):

@Barmar's solution is a little more condensed but I'll post this anyway.

```
list_of_lists_1 = [["1", "3", "5"], ["7", "9", "11"], ["13", "15", "17"]]
list_of_lists_2 = [["2", "4", "6"], ["8", "10", "12"], ["14", "16", "18"]]
person_list = ["person_a", "person_b", "person_c"]

for n,p in enumerate(person_list):
    output = p
    for digits in zip(list_of_lists_1[n],list_of_lists_2[n]):
        output += digits[0]+digits[1]
    print(output)
```

Comment: I updated the desired outcome. My bad. Your code @kpie worked fine in regards to the OLD desired outcome .

Answer (score 1):

By extension of @Barmar's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/71243300/218663) here is how you might do it with a list comprehension:

```py
list_of_lists_1 = [["1", "3", "5"], ["7", "9", "11"], ["13", "15", "17"]]
list_of_lists_2 = [["2", "4", "6"], ["8", "10", "12"], ["14", "16", "18"]]
person_list = ["person_a", "person_b", "person_c"]

result = (
    f"{name}{s1}{s2}"
    for suffixes_1, suffixes_2, name in zip(list_of_lists_1, list_of_lists_2, person_list)
    for s1, s2 in zip(suffixes_1, suffixes_2)
)

for outcome in result:
    print(outcome)
```

Giving you:

```
person_a12
person_a34
person_a56
person_b78
person_b910
person_b1112
person_c1314
person_c1516
person_c1718
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @JonSG. As an inexperienced coder, it is always good to see different code that achieves the same outcome.